# count repeats, number up each repeat instead of the total number of times it repeats

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I am trying to create a formula that counts the repeated values in a column and instead of putting the number of times it is repeated, it lists those repeated:

I have tried with

```
=COUNTIF(CONCATENATE("Y1:Y",ROW(Y88)),Y88)
```

where y88 is the current row and dragging generates the set of formulas for each cell, but it doesn't work.

AND I TRIED WITH:

```
=COUNTIF({Y1:Y+ROW(Y88)},Y88)
```

But it doesn't work either.

Input

```
col1 col2
a   
b   
a   
b   
b   
a
```

Output

```
col1 col2
a   1
b   1
a   2
b   2
b   3
a   3
```

ANY IDEA ON HOW TO MAKE IT IN GOOGLE SHEET OR SCRIPT?

Answer (score 1):

Try `COUNTIFS()` with array formula.

```
=Arrayformula(IF(A2:A="",,COUNTIFS(A2:A, A2:A, ROW(A2:A), "<="&ROW(A2:A))))
```

[image]

Comment: works, but lists them out of order. This formula works for me "=countif($A$1:$A2,$A2)", but I can't apply arrayformula

Comment: @Dandal You formula will work for manual dragging. To make it array approach you need to apply some tricks what I have shown in my answer.

Comment: Could you explain to me how this part of the formula works please: ROW(A2:A), "<="&ROW(A2:A), I don't understand it, I've never seen it that way